# Ruby gem mysql2 install failing

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2, libmysql

When I try to install the mysql2 gem, it fails with no apparent errors. Does anyone know what to do to work around this so mysql2 installs?

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to have 64-bit MySQL installed on your machine, plus the build tools you get when you install xcode.

Comment: That solved it. Installed 64-bit MySQL on my computer via the link below and all worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: yep - `brew install mysql` and then `gem install mysql` **without** problems - thx!

Answer (score 156):

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev  #(mysql development headers)
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/etc/mysql/
```

That's it!

Result:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.2.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
```

Comment: Unfortunately, apt is not yet available on OSX. But your approach does indeed work on Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't understand how this has so many upvotes when it does not correspond to the question.

Comment: It has so many upvotes because others (like myself) have found this useful. It solved my issue.

Comment: Issue is the same problem but on a different OS

Comment: Install another useful gem -    sudo gem install mysql2xxxx -- --with-mysql-dir=/etc/mysql/

Comment: For me the _--with-mysql-dir_ was not enough, and instead I had to use **`sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-include=/usr/include/mysql/ --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql/`**

Comment: this helped me install mysql2 on my chromebook. thanks @tunelko!

Comment: Please not that on Ubuntu 13, at least, you don't have to specify `with-mysql-dir`. Just install `libmysqlclient-dev` and then run `bundle install` and it should work.

Comment: @JoshM.: Fantastic tip. Thanks a lot. Works much smoother that way, including on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: `libmysqlclient-dev` solved my problem in Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

You need the MySQL development headers for mysql2 to properly compile. This is needed, because much of the functionality is written in C and subsequently linked against MySQL.

A solution is to either point the gem installer to your mysql install folder explicitly like so

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
# or where ever you installed your mysql server to
```

or by installing a mysql server to a known location (e.g. by using [homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).) and then installing the gem

```
# install the mysql server locally
brew install mysql
# install the gem
gem install mysql2
```

Both approaches require you to have XCode installed to have the required GCC compiler.

Comment: The brew solution worked the best for me. If you install the Mac OS X MySQL binary make sure to use the 64bit version.

Comment: Thanks, the `--with-mysql-dir=` option was just what I needed to solve my problem.

Comment: For me the `--with-mysql-dir` was actually causing an issue. I just left that off and let it install to a default directory. I just direct installed a specific version with `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.18'`

Comment: Thanks : This worked for me : ==> sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql

Answer (score 27):

With Brew and MySQL installed, I used the following to install the mysql2 gem

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.10/bin/mysql_config
```

If you're using Bundler, you can tell bundler about this with command:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local//Cellar/mysql/5.5.10/bin/mysql_config
```

As documented here: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: This also works if you're using brew versions to install old versions, e.g. brew install mysql51, gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.13' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql51/5.1.71/bin/mysql_config (on mountain lion)

Comment: only solution to this strange problem in MacOS!

Answer (score 9):

on Mac OSX Moutain Lion, below command worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.01 as well!

Comment: On macOS Mojave as well!

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 15.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo gem install mysql2
```

Ubuntu-16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql2
sudo gem install mysql2
```

Output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.19
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.19
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.19
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check this thread at the MySQL web site: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?116,178217,178217, particularly the answer by Scott Derrick: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?116,178217,189357#msg-189357

To be more specific, try using

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In Centos 6.x (7 should work) with SCL (software collection) rh-mysql:

```
scl enable rh-mysql56 bash
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5' -- --with-mysql-include=/opt/rh/rh-mysql56/root/usr/include --with-mysql-lib=/opt/rh/rh-mysql56/root/usr/lib64
```

Answer (score 1):

I dug through 2 days worth of the internet and Stack Overflow, and it wasn't until I found [this link](http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2013/05/gem-install-mysql2-missing-mysqlh-on-os.html) and then starting working through [this ticket for mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/383) that I actually resolved the issue.

With my setup (as explained in the ticket), the compiler switches of -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-unused-private-field would break and give me an error that wasn't exactly correct, which was:

```
mysql.h is missing. please check your installation of mysql and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by being specific on where are the directories, *no need to reinstall anything*, with brew or macports or whatever, just by specifying where are the things (only one thing: the ruby on my mac was installed with rvm, I'm not using the default one that comes with os x):

adding to your `gem install mysql2` the flags below

- `--srcdir="..."` - the includes
- `--with-mysql-dir="..."` - the mysql directory
- `--with-mysql-config="..."` - the mysql_config file

like this `gem install mysql2 --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include/ --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you type `rvm use ruby-2.1.0@rails4.0 --create` in you directory then `bundle install` it works.