# Mysql 2.9.1 error with ruby 2.0

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

OS Ubuntu 12.04.
I`ve cloned rails4.0.0beta1 from https://github.com/rails/rails.git.
I have ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474), when I am trying to do "bundle install" i have the following error message:

```
Installing mysql (2.9.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/zergood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query()... -lmysqlclient
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/zergood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/zergood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/zergood/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: it would be better if you give some information about operation system

Comment: Thnx. I`ve edited the question. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, try something like

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server \
mysql-client mysql-common
```

and then

```
gem install mysql
```

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 only needed to install libmysqld-dev. 
`sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev`

This got me on the right path. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue - installing **Mysql 2.9.1 error with ruby 2.0** but on Mac 10.9.2

The solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115182/775359

`brew install mysql`

> You need the MySQL development headers for mysql2 to properly compile.
>   This is needed, because much of the functionality is written in C and
>   subsequently linked against MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

just a minor correction: `libmysql-ruby`  is phase out, so use `ruby-mysql` instead --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/641943/e-unable-to-locate-package-libmysql-ruby

full command is thus:

`sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql libmysqlclient-dev mysql-server \
mysql-client mysql-common`

and then

`gem install mysql`