# ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am having some problems when trying to install gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17' for Rails. When I try to install it by running gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17' or gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17' it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config

Gem files will remain installed in `..../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql2-0.3.17 for inspection`.
Results logged to `.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out`
```

How can I fix this and successfully install mysql2?

Thanks all .

Comment: Could you include the contents of the `.../gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/mysql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out` file. It is shown in the last line of the error message as `Results logged to.. `

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115126/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-failing

Answer (score 10):

I am in Ubuntu 15.04 and I got the same error as stated above.

I did :

```
 sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

After this I did:

```
gem install mysql2
```

And now I can successfully do

```
rails new <app_name> -d mysql
```

without any errors.

Answer (score 8):

Install libmysqlclient-devel:

CentOS/Fedora:

```
yum install -y libmysqlclient-devel
```

Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev
```

Mac:

```
brew install mysql
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's required for mysql2 gem. Just install it before ``` gem install mysql2 ``` or ``` rails new app_name -d mysql ```.

Comment: On Fedora this worked for me: `yum install mysql-devel`.  (Or rather: `dnf install mysql-devel`)

Answer (score 3):

hi this might be happening for two reason.

1) You did not install your mysql server for that try

```
$ brew install mysql
```

2) didn't specified mysql_config when you are trying to install mysql2 for this try with

```
$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install MySQL server first. You probably don't have it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, i have mysql but don't have mysql2 .

Comment: There you go, head over to the oracle website and install it on your machine. When you're done, gem will install